# How to run also ignored tests in JUnit 4 from command line?

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, junit4

I would like to run some ignored tests from a java program's main method in JUnit 4. They are ignored because they only insert some data for demonstration purpose.

in my main method:

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
junit.run(MyClass.class);
```

However this will not run test classes annotated with @Ignored

```
@Ignore("Only for filling system with demo data")
public class MyClass { ... }
```

In IntelliJ I can run those by right clicking on the class. How can I run them from the command line / in a main method?

I saw the Runner IgnoredClassRunner but not sure how to use that and if that is the correct Runner/Class.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove or comment out @Ignore?

Comment: The tests are long running and insert demo data. they are ment to generate a lot of (partially random) data locally. now I would like to allow some OP on a remote serve I dont have access to execute these tests.

Comment: It sounds like these are not tests then. In which case, they should be refactored as stand-alone code?

Comment: @Duncan probably but first I would like to use that as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this is quite easy achievable with:

```
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
junit.run(new BlockJUnit4ClassRunner(MyClass.class));
```

I will leave this answer open if anybody comes up with something better, which just prevents IgnoredClassRunner to be invoked for classes annotated with @Ignored

Comment: The Javadoc says:     /*** Do not use. Testing purposes only. */ public Result run(Runner runner) {